# PHP / Xampp / PDO - Connect locally with xampp to a online database with the PDO library in PHP

Tags: php, pdo, xampp

Basically the title,

When I attempt to connect to a database I get the error: `could not find driver`.

I've searched online and it was said I had to uncomment several extensions.
I uncommented `extension=php_pgsql.dll` and `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` in the `php.ini` in `C:\xampp\php`, but that didnt solve it.

When I run my code on the online server the database connection works.
I'm using PDO for the database to a MSSQL server.

Basic information:

- I'm using XAMPP Control Panel V3.2.2 on Windows
- I connect like so:

  ```
  define("USER_NAME", "myusername");
  define("DATABASE", "mydatabase");
  define("PASSWORD", "mypassword");
  define("HOST", "myhost");

  try{
      $db = new PDO("dblib:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DATABASE, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
      $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }catch(PDOException $exception){
      echo $exception->getMessage();
      exit;
  }
  ```

**EDIT**

I downloaded MSSQL driver for PDO.
I added these two extensions:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

Without success.

Comment: `dblib` iirc is for MSSQL, the extensions you describe are for PostgreSQL. So which one is it? Are you connecting to MSSQL, or Postgres, or something else entirely.

Comment: oo my bad. I'm using MSSQL actually. Should I uncomment other extensions?

Comment: Yes, have a look at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) for dblib. You're looking specifically for a dblib dll.

Comment: @JonStirling I've downloaded the driver. I updated my question, could you check it?

Comment: What's the latest error? Have you restarted the webserver / php processes (depending on set up) after you changes the files?

Comment: It's the same error. "Could not find driver". I've restarted xampp multiple times ;P

Comment: Check the output from `phpinfo()` and see if the driver is showing up in there.

Answer (score 0):

-EDIT-

You enabled the wrong extension to use MSSQL database.

So you could check the [dblib](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) docs for the dll (tip from https://stackoverflow.com/users/934966/jon-stirling).

-ORIGINAL-

You forgot the database server port by the host (host=".HOST.":".PORT.";):

```
define("USER_NAME", "myusername");
define("DATABASE", "mydatabase");
define("PASSWORD", "mypassword");
define("HOST", "myhost");
define("PORT", "10060");

try{
    $db = new PDO("dblib:host=".HOST.":".PORT.";dbname=".DATABASE, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $exception){
    echo $exception->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

Hope this works!

More information:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Comment: Port is not a required part of the DSN.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use PDO_dblib in XAMPP3.2.2

[This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)

On Windows, you should use [SqlSrv](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)